# Excel (2007) function does not calculate when I open the file (Automatic calculation)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a function via vba and I have used this function to make an iterative table. I have set the workbook calculation to automatic and it all works fine but when I open the excel file, the cells that contain the mentioned function, give me #name error and everytime I need to recalculate. Is there a way to fix this?

```
Public Function FrictionFactor(relativeroughness, reynoldsnumber)

    'Dim relativeroughness, reynoldsnumber As Double
    fNext = 0.005               ' initial value for f
    fIncrement = 0.005          ' initial step size
    Convergence = 0.000001      ' sets the decimal place accuracy of the result

    Do

        fStart = fNext
        LHSColebrookStart = 1 / (fStart ^ 0.5)
        RHSColebrookStart = -2 * (Log((relativeroughness / 3.7) + (2.51 / (reynoldsnumber * (fStart ^ 0.5)))) / Log(10))
        DifferenceStart = LHSColebrookStart - RHSColebrookStart

        fNext = fStart + fIncrement
        LHSColebrookNext = 1 / (fNext ^ 0.5)
        RHSColebrookNext = -2 * (Log((relativeroughness / 3.7) + (2.51 / (reynoldsnumber * (fNext ^ 0.5)))) / Log(10))
        DifferenceNext = LHSColebrookNext - RHSColebrookNext

        If DifferenceStart * DifferenceNext < 0 Then        ' march f in opposite direction and more slowly
            fIncrement = fIncrement / -10
        ElseIf DifferenceStart * DifferenceNext = 0 Then    ' done
            fIncrement = 0
        End If                                              ' keep marching f in same direction and at same rate

    Loop While Abs(fStart - fNext) > Convergence

    FrictionFactor = fStart
End Function
```

Comment: Whats the code in the UDF?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Post the VBA code in your function.

Comment: no, I commented that section out because dimensioning them as double gives me "Duplicate declaration within scope" error.

Comment: UDF stands for User Defined Function, in other words a function made by a user.

Comment: Where is this function located? It should be in a general module either in the workbook where it is being used, or in an addin or in Persinal.XLS or similar.

Comment: I loaded the function as an addin and now it works fine, thanks a lot for that! also a useful link : 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2007-HA010218996.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason this happens is that macros are not enabled when the workbook is opened.  Check your Security settings.

Comment: Macros are enabled all th time, so when the workbook is opened, they are active by default.

Comment: What is the name of the udf??

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by UDF or how I could get its name